# Porquê não consigo fazer o mapeamento utilizando o Automapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Tenho uma model chamada **Cliente** com muitos atributos e (por uma questão de simplicidade coloquei aqui apenas alguns) pensei em criar ***ViewModels*** para simplificar a exibição dos dados nas ***Views***, o problema é que o mapeamento que estou fazendo (utilizando o [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org)) não funciona.

Este é o mapeamento:

```
CreateMap<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>()
    .ForMember(e => e.IDCliente, v => v.MapFrom(s => s.IDCliente))
    .ForMember(e => e.IDCliente, v => v.MapFrom(s => s.EnderecoViewModel.IDCliente))
    .ForMember(e => e.IDCliente, v => v.MapFrom(s => s.ContatoViewModel.IDCliente));
```

Este é o método Json que efetua o mapeamento. 
Notem que eu estou setando o valor 1000 para o atributo model.IDCliente, porém depois que o mapeamento é executado o valor de modelMapping.IDCLiente é igual a 0.

```
public JsonResult ItemClienteAtendimentoHist(ClienteViewModel model)
{
    model.IDCliente = 1000;
    string mensagem = "";
    try
    {
        var modelMapping = Mapper.Map<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>(model);
        var retCliente = _ctx.ObterCliente(modelMapping);
        return Json(new { Cliente = retCliente, success = true, message = mensagem }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { message = ex.Message, success = false });
    }
}
```

**ViewModels:**

```
public class ClienteViewModel{
public int IDCliente {get; set;}
public string NomeCliente  {get; set;}
public string CPFCliente  {get; set;}
public EnderecoViewModel EnderecoViewModel {get; set;}
public ContatoViewModel ContatoViewModel {get; set;}
}

public class EnderecoViewModel{
public int IDCliente  {get; set;}
public string LogradouroEndreco  {get; set;}
public string NumeroEndereco  {get; set;}
public string CEPEndereco  {get; set;}
public ClienteViewModel ClienteViewModel {get; set;}
}

public class ContatoViewModel{
public string public int IDCliente  {get; set;}
public string NomeContato  {get; set;}
public string TelContato  {get; set;}
public ClienteViewModel ClienteViewModel {get; set;}
}
```

**Model Cliente:**

```
public class Cliente{
public int IDCliente  {get; set;}
public string NomeCliente  {get; set;}
public string CPFCliente  {get; set;}
public string LogradouroEndreco  {get; set;}
public string NumeroEndereco  {get; set;}
public string CEPEndereco  {get; set;}
public string NomeContato {get; set;}
public string TelContato  {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No trecho abaixo você está mapeando três vezes o mesmo elemento de destino sendo que o último que ele está atribuindo é o `s.ContatoViewModel.IDCliente`.

```
CreateMap<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>()
    .ForMember(e => e.IDCliente, v => v.MapFrom(s => s.IDCliente))
    .ForMember(e => e.IDCliente, v => v.MapFrom(s => s.EnderecoViewModel.IDCliente))
    .ForMember(e => e.IDCliente, v => v.MapFrom(s => s.ContatoViewModel.IDCliente));
```

Leia a documentação do `automapper`. [Aqui tem uma explicação](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Projection.html) pra isso que está tentando fazer.

Pra que você entenda melhor, segue abaixo um exemplo do que você está fazendo:

A propriedade `ClienteViewModel.IDCliente` que está com o valor `1000`, no entanto você em nenhum momento atribuiu valor nas propriedades `EnderecoViewModel.IDCliente` ou `ContatoViewModel.IDCliente` e **por serem do tipo `int` vão estar com valor 0**.

No código mais acima que disse estar com erro de lógica ele basicamente faz as seguintes atribuições:

```
Cliente.IDCliente = 1000; //.ForMember(e => e.IDCliente, v => v.MapFrom(s => s.IDCliente))
Cliente.IDCliente = 0; //.ForMember(e => e.IDCliente, v => v.MapFrom(s => s.EnderecoViewModel.IDCliente))
Cliente.IDCliente = 0; //.ForMember(e => e.IDCliente, v => v.MapFrom(s => s.ContatoViewModel.IDCliente))
```

Como o nome e o tipo da propriedade é exatamente o mesmo na origem e no destino você pode fazer apenas isso:

```
CreateMap<ClienteViewModel, Cliente>();
```